# How to convert the code in python3.6.2 to python2.6.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have written code in python3.6.2, but in my production servers python2.6.6 is available, what are all the syntax will differ?

I have used print, if else, for loops, functions, lists in my Python 3.6.2.

Please help me.

Comment: So, what have you tried and what is not working?

Comment: Well, running it should tell you if any SyntaxErrors exist... If you are using external libraries, then you'd need to install those, which means you might have admin permissions, and therefore you have access to install Python3 as well

Comment: Read https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html

Answer (score 2):

From the python docs:

> To help with staying compatible, any new modules you create should
>   have at least the following block of code at the top of it:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
```

This will solve the parentheses issue in print, 5/2 = 2.5(in python3) vs 2(in python2). But, there might be some other issues as well. You need to manually check and correct those.

Comment: i tried calling a function as below 
    myfunc(Formid, Formvalue)

where formid and formvalue is assigned some value before calling the function, 
i am getting NameError: name 'FormId' is not defined

Comment: That is most certainly not a version compatibility issue, but maybe some issue in your code. Please make sure that it works in python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

**Print statements**

Python 2:

```
print 'Hello, World!'  
print('Hello, World!')  
print "text", ; print 'print more text on the same line'
```

Python 3:

```
print('Hello, World!') 
print("some text,", end="") 
print(' print more text on the same line')
```

**For Loops**

Python 2:

```
i = 1
print 'before: i =', i
print 'comprehension: ', [i for i in range(5)]
print 'after: i =', i
```

Python 3:

```
i = 1
print('before: i =', i)
print('comprehension:', [i for i in range(5)])
print('after: i =', i)
```

Answer (score -1):

The main difference is parentheses () as they are used more often in python 3 than two

for example in python 3:
    print(string)

and in python 2:
    print string

so this is the main change you would have to make (print statement).

There are also two open source programs to convert code (you can find on PyPI.org):

2to3 - for converting python 2 to python 3

3to2 - for converting python 3 to python 2

these work often but are not perfect